# How to select a single column and group array

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I want to select a single column in mgo which is array of strings currently using this returns a empty array

```
classifiedColl.Find(nil).Distinct("Tags", &tags)
```

and i want to group it how do i do it. The value i want to group is array of strings.

Comment: Group it based on what, same value for same key or based on a predefined values? Please update the grouping criteria

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful. And keep in mind that your are not talking to subordinates, but to peers.